# Error: no matching function for call C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am new to C++. I have implemented a B+ tree and it is working fine on Macbook (with CLion) but when I run it on a ubuntu server it gives the compilation error below. Can someone help with this please?

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> 
>::vector(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, 
std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, 
std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator)’
```

Result of g++ -v on Mac:

*Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin*

Result of g++ -v on ubuntu server:

*gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)*

Code snippet where error is thrown:

```
    std::pair<InternalNode *, Node *> split(int order) {
    std::vector<float>::const_iterator old_dn_keys_end = keys.begin() + ceil(float(order) / 2) - 2;
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator old_dn_values_end = values.begin() + ceil(float(order) / 2) - 2;
    new_dn->keys = std::vector<float>(old_dn_keys_end + 1, keys.end());

   //**--- error here ---**
   new_dn->values = std::vector<std::string>(old_dn_values_end + 1, 
   values.end());
   //rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing a `std::vector` with iterators requires them to be the same type. It looks like you're constructing it with a `vector<>::const_iterator` and a `vector<>::iterator` (via `.end()`).

Either make `old_dn_values_end` a non-const iterator or use `.cend()`.